# adding a clickable image in swift to redirect to another view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, swift

i am a beginner in IOS programming. and i was wondering on how to add a clickable image by the user touching the image that redirects them to another ViewController. Im stuck, i have tried researching it up , and haven't found nothing really to help me

Comment: What's the hard part? Do you not know how to detect a touch on the image? Do you not know how to go to a different view controller? What?

Comment: making the clickable image

Comment: So learn about UIImageView (shows the image) and UITapGestureRecognizer (detects the touch).

Comment: any good beginner guides on learning objective C?

Comment: I'm not permitted to answer that. I can advise you to read the docs, of course. They are on your computer and are excellent.

Comment: I suppose I'm allowed to point you to the online version of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/

Answer (score 4):

If your using storyboard, this is pretty straightforward.

Drop your UIImageView where you want it, size and add whatever layout you want.

Drag a Tap Gesture Recognizer on top of the UIImageView.

Control-click and drag from the gesture recognizer to the second view controller and create a seque.

[Quick Video Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaHuyG-gHfk&feature=youtube_gdata_player)